# Highcharts set percent to datatable

Tags: highcharts

As you can see on this JSFiddle, I want to show "%" to values in the dataTable below the graph : http://jsfiddle.net/fa32gywh/

I tried every options in my options :

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{y} %'
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value}%'
    }
},
```

It works for my graph, but not the data in the dataTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style the table with css.  Note that my selector works because you only have one series If you had multiple, you would have to be more specific.

```
.highcharts-data-table td.number:after {
  content: '%'
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fa32gywh/1/